# Append row bind multiple data frames with varying rows and columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, rbind

I am reading many data files with similar (not identical) columns. 4 to 20 columns exist in different files.

Attempting to create a single data.frame row binding each file to others. Where matching columns shall form a single column in result. Rows with Missing columns get NA.

Unlike earlier questions : the number and exact names of data columns are known 'only' after reading each file. The maximum number of columns that will be in the output data frame need to be generated as data is read.

E.g.

df1 has columns  "DEPTH","GR_norm","NeuHyCorr", "DenHyCorr","DT", "UWI"

df2 has columns  "DEPTH","GR_norm","DenHyCorr", "NeuHyCorr", "PHIE", "RRT", "UWI"

df3 has columns  "DEPTH","GR_norm","DenHyCorr", "NeuHyCorr", "RRT", "Rocktype", "UWI"

.....

I am doing rbind in a for loop: data is read into data.frame - temp in each loop iteration and merged with following code

if (wellno == 1) welldata <- temp else welldata <- rbind(welldata, temp)

it fails with

> Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
>     numbers of columns of arguments do not match

Tried `merge()` in place of `rbind` with failure.

I expect to see welldata having all the columns of the individual data frames.

Comment: Use `dplyr::bind_rows()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)

df1 = data.frame(a=1:2,b=letters[1:2])
df2 = data.frame(b=letters[3:4],c=c('dog','cat'))

rbind.fill(list(df1, df2))
#   a b    c
#1  1 a <NA>
#2  2 b <NA>
#3 NA c  dog
#4 NA d  cat
```

Or `data.table` package using `rbindlist` with fill option to `TRUE` (however this will give you a data.table object):

```
rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill=T)
#    a b   c
#1:  1 a  NA
#2:  2 b  NA
#3: NA c dog
#4: NA d cat
```

Comment: for (nw in 1:nwells) {...      temp<- read.table(lasfile[nw], header=T)  ...  if( nw ==1) welldata <- temp else welldata <- rbind.fill(list(welldata, temp))      ...} Works well!!!      Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`:

```
df1 = data.frame(a=1:2,b=letters[1:2])
df2 = data.frame(b=letters[3:4],c=c('dog','cat'))
bind_rows(df1, df2)
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]

      a     b      c
  (int) (chr) (fctr)
1     1     a     NA
2     2     b     NA
3    NA     c    dog
4    NA     d    cat
```

For many dataframes, store them in a list (or vector) and combine it with `Reduce`, as in

```
# list of 10 different dataframes:
df_list <- lapply(1:10, 
             function(x) setNames(data.frame(rnorm(1)), sample(letters[1:3],1)))

Reduce(bind_rows, df_list)
Source: local data frame [10 x 3]

            a          b         c
        (dbl)      (dbl)     (dbl)
1  -1.6825270         NA        NA
2          NA -0.4742396        NA
3          NA  0.1676438        NA
4          NA  1.0191025        NA
5          NA -0.1836922        NA
6   0.1188567         NA        NA
7          NA  0.4464885        NA
8  -1.2886858         NA        NA
9   0.3945049         NA        NA
10         NA         NA 0.3039996
```